# Safari skips website header and goes to content

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I noticed that when I open my website on iPhone or iPad and I go to an article page, somehow the browser detects beginning of an article, omits a header and scrolls down to an article content, so user does not have a chance of seeing header of my site and adverts that are above my header. How can I disable that behavior of Safari or at least trick it so it stays at the top of my page?

Comment: Please can you provide a reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes sure, if you visit this article for example: http://www.alt.dk/mit-liv/samfund/derfor-er-modne-kvinder-blevet-sa-hotte/
using iPhone or iPad and you will wait till it loads, you will see that then it scrolls down to an image, leaving a banner and a site menu behind.

Comment: It's not just Safari, it also happens on Chrome mobile browser.

Comment: It appears to be a problem in your javascript.  When I load the page on Safari Desktop, it snaps to the content, hiding the banner and the menu unless I manually scroll up after the page loads.  When I use the develop menu in Safari (desktop version), I disable javascript.  After reloading the page, it correctly loads with the menu showing (not the banner though, since that is loaded via javascript).

Comment: Check the JQuery UI Slide js code.  That is responsible for sliding elements out of the viewport, and is probably where the problem is originating.

Comment: Just to say that the issue doesn't replicate on Android tablet or Windows phone; however, I have seen issues in iOS with DOM elements having focus on page load causing the browser to scroll to that point. As for a hack to trick the browser to jump to the top of the page, there is javascript for this but it will cause the browser to lose a users page position on refresh which isn't recommended.

Comment: Yes, as AndW99 said, the problem appears only in Safari, it doesn't appear in browsers like Chrome, IE, Firefox or Edge so actually it seems to be something that Safari does. I'll have a look at jQuery UI as suggested but it seems to me that if it was something with js I included myself then the problem would appear in other browsers as well.

Comment: But yeah, you're right about Chrome - the same behaviour appers there but again - only on iPads and iPhones - it doesn't scroll down in Chrome on Windows or Android. Must be some Apple thing I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out what's the reason for it! But thank you guys for the help and hints.

So the problem is that on Apple browsers/devices there is an event 'popstate' that is fired on a load of a page. That does not happen in Windows Chrome, IE, Firefox etc. And the reason it scrolls me down is that I use History and I change an url of the site when I scroll down to another article. Then when an user clicks back button in his browser, 'popstate' event is fired and on that event I scroll to a beginning of a previous article. So since in Apple connnected browsers there is an additional popstate event on a page load, it scrolls me to the first article right away. Here's a hack that prevents that behaviour:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', popStateHandler, false);
    }, 0);
}, false);
```